# After changes on a storyboard ViewController, the elements modified still takes old values

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I have make some updates from my storyboard on differents objects inside a ViewController.

Also, I have a method which customize my UITextFields with shadow, rounded corners etc :

```
-(void)createShadowBordersToView:(UIView *) view{
    UIView * whiteRoundedCornerView;
    whiteRoundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
    whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, 2);
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
    [self.container insertSubview:whiteRoundedCornerView belowSubview:view];
}
```

as you can see I put an UIView under my textfield with some style to create the illusion that the textfield is customized. I create this view with the origin and the size of the UITextView passed in parameter.

However, since I've updated the position and the width of my UITextFields from storyboard, this method always init a UIView with the old positions and width (my frames are well updated from my storyboard and I have no warnings).

So now, I have all my UITextFields with the right position and the right size, but their background views are still at the old position and they have old size (before my updates).

My view controller from my story board :

[image: storyboard]

My results :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove the app from device / simulator, clean your project and reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

Well it was a bad idea to create an UIView to customize my textfields, I manage directly the layer of my textfields and now everything work fine.